# Linux Script to remove lines that match dates

Tags: linux, bash

I have a log file that includes lines that are formatted like the following below. I am trying to create a script in Linux that will remove the lines older then x days from the current date.

```
Wed Jan 26 10:44:35 2022 : Auth: (72448)   Login incorrect (mschap: MS-CHAP2-Response is incorrect): [martin.zeus] (from client CoreNetwork port 0 via TLS tunnel)    
Wed Jan 16 10:45:32 2022 : Auth: (72482) Login OK: [george.kye] (from client CoreNetwork port 5 cli CA-93-F0-6C-7E-77)
```

Comment: Can you share your attempt? It may help to build off of that and how you are going about solving this as one could use `python`, `awk`, `sed`, `bash`, etc

Comment: And a silly question ... why don't you let `logrotate` take care of this for you? Why try to reinvent the wheel (most likely poorly)?

Comment: Thank you tink. I thought logrotate wasn't an option because this is on a synology nas. Turns out its installed by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take a look at [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) and [Kibana & Elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/es/kibana/) to parse and filter the logs.

Nevertheless, I made a simple script that prints only the entries from the day that you pass as an argument until the current date,

E.g. This will print only the logs since the last 5 days. `bash filter.sh log.txt 5`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file="${1}"
days="${2:-1}"

epoch_days=$(date -d "now -${days} days" +%s)

OFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
while read line; do
    epoch_log=$(date --date="$(echo $line | cut -d':' -f1,2,3)" +%s)
    if [ ${epoch_log} -ge ${epoch_days} ]; then
        echo ${line}
    fi
done < ${file}
IFS=$OFS
```

Comment: Like the approach. A couple of tips. Always double-quote variables in `[ ... ]`.  Always double-quote filenames (your user may do something dumb like have spaces in them) Additionally, variables in ALLCAPS are generally reserved for system and environment variables. Also, emphasize that your solution is a bash solution. (`$'\n'` is a bashism) It's not clear what the shell is from tags [linux] and [script]. Still, good effort and still worth the nod for that.

Comment: Thanks rcedillo. This works as well.